# Inserting external code into div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to build an image gallery where pressing on the related button will display (and write) into a hidden div.  Using jquery, I can get it to show/hide the div, and even load the specified image.  But when I try putting everything in an external file (to minimise code duplication), I'm getting nothing.

Primary html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/full.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="img-container" style="display: none;">

    </div>


    <button id="view-more">Show</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var imgWrite = $('<img src="img/photos/image0000-0.png" />');

    $("#view-more").click(function(){
            $("#img-container").css('display', 'flex');
             $('#img-container').load("galleries/gallery01.txt"
        
    });
       
    $("#close").click(function(){   
     $("#img-container").css('display', 'none');
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Edited post:
Loaded from an external text file

```
<button id="close">Close</button>
<img src="img/photos/image0000-0.png" />
<div id="info">
<h4>Title</h4>
<h5>Artist</h5>
<h5>Medium</h5>
<h6>Notes</h6>
</div>
```

Edit:  I fixed the missing close paren,the button and the background styles loaded, but still no image or headers.

Comment: You're missing the `)` at the end of the `.load(` call. Didn't you see the syntax error message in the console?

Comment: You can't load an entire HTML file into a DIV. There can only be one `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` in the DOM.

Comment: You could use an iframe instead of a DIV. `$("#iframeid").attr("src", "galleries/gallery01.html");`

Comment: I had originally loaded the content from an external text file, went back to that, and fixed the missing close paren.  Neither the image, nor headers load, though.

Previous attempts had the button already inside the hidden div, and using .append into the id would load the image, but once I tried adding the inner div and headers, the same problem with nothing loading would occur.
  Using an external file was just an attempt to make the code cleaner, and also make it easier to change information (title, artist, notes) contained in the h4-h6 without having to change code in the page itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try again with the Ajax method?

```
$("#view-more").click(function(){
    $("#img-container").css('display', 'flex');
    
    $.ajax({
        url : "galleries/gallery01.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $('#img-container').html(data);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Why would this be any better? That's exactly what `.load()` is a shortcut for.

Comment: I'm getting the background specified in the CSS and nothing from the text file.  I'm wondering, though, if these methods expect to be dealing with a server, and since I'm testing all the files locally that might be where I'm having problems.  I'm going to upload everything and then give it another go.

Comment: It worked, and did just need a server in there.

Comment: Barmar, I don't know objectively if it's a better method to solve the problem, but having to look up ajax did point me to the problem, namely, the underlying stuff using server requests made it so that nothing happened when testing locally without apache running.  If nothing else, it exposed a flaw in the way I was approaching the code/testing, even if unintentionally.

And thankfully, I have a raspberry pi that I can turn into a dev server.